# ListObjectVersionsCommand - multiple files

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a type

```
export  type Students = {
    [key: string]: {
        age: number,
        gender: string,
        nationality: string
      
    }[]
}
```

where the key is 'computing', 'science' etc. and this returns an array of students

```
{ studentData.map(({ age, gender, nationality }: Students ) => {

    return { // stuff }

    })
}
```

How do I type the map? I have tried

**Students[key:string]**

**Students**

etc.

I need to type the deconstructed array within the Students type.